# Raspberry pi pico w unable to import dht module

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I was using a dht22 sensor in my raspberry pi pico w board but suddenly I can't anymore

I get the following error when trying to import dht module:

```
ValueError: incompatible .mpy file
```

I tried updating the micropython firmware to the latest version but the problem persists.
My DHT22 module is a bit faulty since I connected it backwards  the first time, but it was working ok, sometimes it emits a high pitched noise, but after reconnecting it it worked normally, now It emits the sound constantly.

However the error appears regardless of the sensor being connected or not, just by calling "import dht" without any extra code.
The rest of the functions of the board are still working, I can blink the led, drive a relay module, run a web server, all the other functions of my application work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the files loaded in my board an extra file was present:
dht.mpy
The file had contents from my log function (a function I use to write exceptions to a file)

I have no clue how this happened, but deleting it solved the problem

Comment: You can likely go back through your shell's history file (in your user directory, e.g. `~/.bash_history` for bash) and find out why it happened and make sure you don't do it again... Typing `history | grep dht.mpy` will likely show you the errant command.

Comment: The pico w board doesn't use linux, is more like an arduino board @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Uhh... I know, I've got about 6 of them, with the DHT22 sensor. Your comment of the micropython file had the contents from my log function -- would indicate you overwrote it somehow. My thought was it was corrupted before the transfer to the Pico -- thus checking your history file on the machine you use to transfer to the pico.

Comment: I use Thonny in windows, no batch history, but the board was working standalone and suddenly failed, the only uncommon thing was there was a power variation at the time (my laptop made the sound of the power cord plugging and unplugging like 3-4 times). When the board failed to work I tried to power off and power it on again but the watchdog kept restarting it. After that is when I connected it to my laptop.  My only guest is somehow a bit in memory moved and the pointer to the log file name changed places with the mpy filename. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had just presumed a Linux development box. It sounds like the micropython file dht.mpy was somehow corrupted in the process. Sounds like you have it sorted out now. Good luck with you pico development. Give Msys2 and C with gcc a go. Msys2 provides an excellent gcc development environment on windows that allows you to use the Pico C API. No need for micropython on the Pico then. Up to you. Either way works well, you just get a bit more low-level control with the C SDK.